# Please help no one knows what's wrong

Tags: engine, starting, maintenance, wiring

I have a 2008 Chevy Equinox went to start it and nothing no sounds nothing all lights and gauges work battery is fully powered had it towed to garage and they said it was starter so we replaced it still nothing they can't seem to find what is wrong they say it's something with the security system. I need help please if anyone can help

Comment: Are the remote keys functioning correctly? What else has been checked?

Comment: Battery in the key? Web search says red security light will be on if issue with security system